# Add new column "Block description" on block layout page

Tags: 8, blocks

I need to add a new column called **Block Short Description** on Block layout under /admin/structure/block.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve it?

I have Attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a form. Themed as table. So I managed to do what you want via `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`.

Thing is, I can't find the block description or admin label inside the block entity. So that's left. I hope you can find a way or maybe you can specify what "Block Short Description" is supposed to be.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_block_admin_display_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Add header column.
  array_splice($form['blocks']['#header'], 1, 0, 'Description');

  // Go through all blocks.
  foreach ($form['blocks'] as $bid => $block) {

    // Skip non-block elements (like '#header' or 'region-name').
    if ($bid[0] != '#' && !strpos($bid, '-')) {

      // Load block.
      $entity = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($bid);

      // Load description.
      // ksm($entity);
      // Can't find one. Take the label for now. Let OP figure this out themselves.
      $description = $entity->label();

      // Add description column to row.
      // @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354804/2199525
      $array = $form['blocks'][$bid];
      $form['blocks'][$bid] = array_slice($array, 0, 2, TRUE) +
        ['description' => ['#markup' => $description]] +
        array_slice($array, 2, count($array) - 1, TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

---

#### Answer updated to display content type restrictions.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_block_admin_display_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Add header column.
  array_splice($form['blocks']['#header'], 1, 0, 'Description');

  // Go through all blocks.
  foreach ($form['blocks'] as $bid => $block) {

    // Skip non-block elements (like '#header' or 'region-name').
    if ($bid[0] != '#' && !strpos($bid, '-')) {

      // Load block.
      $entity = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($bid);

      // Load visibility settings.
      $conditions = $entity->getVisibilityConditions()->getConfiguration();

      // Load content types.
      $types = [];
      if ($node_types = isset($conditions['node_type']['bundles']) ? $conditions['node_type']['bundles'] : FALSE) {
        $node_types = Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::loadMultiple($node_types);
        foreach ($node_types as $node_type) {
          $types[] = $node_type->label();
        }
      }

      // Set description.
      $description = 'Content types: ';
      if (!empty($types)) {
        $description .= implode(', ', $types);
      }
      else {
        $description = '- no content type restrictions -';
      }

      // Add description column to row.
      // @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354804/2199525
      $array = $form['blocks'][$bid];
      $form['blocks'][$bid] = array_slice($array, 0, 2, TRUE) +
        ['description' => ['#markup' => $description]] +
        array_slice($array, 2, count($array) - 1, TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually I need to display **content type assigned to the specific blocks** under Description column. Can you please let me know how to achieve this by above code?

Comment: @Selvamesk – Updated answer.

Comment: Really you are awesome!!! Its working as I expected. Along with this, Is there any possibility to display **Pages assigned to the specific blocks**?

Comment: @Selvamesk – It's all there already. Simply checkout what else you find inside `$conditions`.

Comment: I have checked this and its request_path & pages but its not giving the result exactly. That's why.

Answer (score 2):

**Some general method**

- Find a unique interface string in the page and look in the core
- Search for the URL of the page and find which routing.yml contains it. Then you will see which class handles the request

**In your case it's the second**

Route name: `block.admin_display`

Controller: `\Drupal\block\Controller\BlockListController`

which in the end is pointing to the Block entity list builder:

```
\Drupal\block\BlockListBuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @leymannx answer, if you want to display the block's admin label instead of the rendered label (which may be the same when you have many blocks), you can try:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_block_admin_display_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    array_splice($form['blocks']['#header'], 1, 0, 'Description');

    foreach ($form['blocks'] as $bid => $block) {
        if ($bid[0] != '#' && false === strpos($bid, '-')) {

            $entity = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($bid);
            $description = $entity->getPlugin()->getPluginDefinition()['admin_label'];
            $array = $form['blocks'][$bid];
            $form['blocks'][$bid] = array_slice($array, 0, 2, TRUE) +
                ['description' => ['#markup' => $description]] +
                array_slice($array, 2, count($array) - 1, TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```